# jQuery horizontally scroll separate objects together

Tags: jquery

I have a code pen here - https://codepen.io/mt-ttmt/pen/NMRBBe

Its simply two divs in a container.

Both div scroll horizontally separately.

Is it possible to scroll both together when scrolling one

So if you scroll the top div the both one scrolls as well or vise versa

```
(function(){

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    $(".content-top").scrollLeft(function() {
      $(".content-bottom").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
    });

  })

})
```

code posted here

```js
$(function(){
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    
    $(".content-top").scrollLeft(function() {
      $(".content-bottom").scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 500px;
}

.scroll-top{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroll-bottom{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content{
  width: 2500px;
  height: 50px;
}

.scroll-top {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black , lightgreen);
}
  
.scroll-bottom {
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  yellow, black);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scroll-top">
    <div class=" content content-top">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-bottom">
    <div class=" content content-bottom">

    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: _"I have a code pen here'_ Wonderful. Please post a [mcve] here. You are about halfway there now so it won't take much effort.

Comment: use jquery's `add(...)` to add both elements to the same jquery object

Comment: j08691 - the code doesn't work if I post here

Comment: @ttmt That's because you need to include jquery.

Comment: I did include jQuery

Comment: Sorry my mistake I did add jquery but deleted the script tag by mistake

Comment: All good =) That's why I edited it quick.

Comment: But the code still doesn't run here

Comment: @ttmt You mean because of the missing colors in each section?

Comment: Sorry yes it was missing semicolons but now you cant see the scrolling haha

Answer (score 0):

Code inside:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {


})
```

will work only after body scroll.

also you need to use parent div with overflow option.

```js
  $('.scroll-top').scroll(function() {
    $('.scroll-bottom').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
  });
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 500px;
}
.scroll-top{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.scroll-bottom{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.content{
  width: 1500px;
  height: 50px;
  }
.content-top{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black , lightgreen);
  }
 .content-bottom{
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  yellow, black);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="scroll-top">
    <div class="content content-top">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-bottom">
    <div class="content content-bottom">
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```